# Python socket subprocess connection reply nothing after a while

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

I'm using python socket to communicate with the backend service (B<->C as the following structure shows):

```
                spawn                    Popen
 NodeJS server ------- Python Subprocess ------ backend process
         A                      B                     C
```

Every time when I start the socket, it works great - but when I stop testing it, after several hours when I test it again, it will not return answer.

I've heard that there could be a issue that:

> If the client is disconnected for some reason, you will get EOF (an
>   empty string) from conn.recv. Then you will write and flush an empty
>   string (zero bytes) to p.stdin which is a no-op. Your subprocess will
>   then wait forever.

But how can I solve this issue?

I improved my code but is still not working. Here are the code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, port))
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
s.listen(10)

conn, addr = s.accept()

while(conn):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    while(data):
        if not data:
            break
        p.stdin.write(data)
        p.stdin.flush()
        result = p.stdout.readline()
        conn.sendall(result)
        break
    conn.close()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
s.close()
```

Any idea to improve the code? Thank you.

Comment: Try searching for concepts like Timeout or Keep Alive.

Answer (score 0):

The program's logic is:

```
while connected:
    send request from network peer to backend
    send reply from backend to network peer
```

The reason it breaks down easily is because it assumes that one network read returns one request. However with network stream (i.e. TCP) there are no guarantees about data boundaries. The input could arrive in one packet, but also in several network packets and multiple reads (or recvs) may be needed to get the whole data - even if the other end sent it in one network write.

When an incomplete request is sent to the backend for processing, the program waits for a reply, while the backend still waits for the rest of the request. The communication is out of sync and a deadlock is the result.

To fix it both programs must follow communication protocol rules. When to send, what to send and when to receive.